# Automatically update price

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic table where there is a span containing a price that might change as I use filters.

As soon as the page loads I need to grab the content of the span and multiply that number per 4.

I don't understand how I can keep the price dynamic when the user filters out the table. 
For example, if currently the span has £100 (price per person) and I run the code it will automatically update to £400, but if I filter out the table or refresh the page, and the price per person changes to £50, the code will return (£400x4) instead of taking the new amount (£50*4)

I hope someone can help me.

This is the script file:

```
function updateGrid() {
  $(".grid_3").each(function(){
    var pp = $(this).find(".latest-offer-price").text();
    var price = Number(pp.substring(1, pp.length));
    var familyPrice = "£" + price * 4;
    $(this).find(".latest-offer-price").text(familyPrice);
   })
 }
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
  setTimeout(updateGrid,30)
});
updateGrid();`
```

This is the html for it:

```
`<div class="grid_3 alpha omega selected">
  <div>
   <p class="latest-type">
     <span class="latest-offer-price">£100</span> 
     <span>pp</span> 
   </p>
  </div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the behavior of your code.
When you run the function that update the prices just replace the previous one with the new one. Then it's exactly the same.

```js
function updateGrid() {
  $(".grid_3").each(function(){
    var pp = $(this).find(".latest-offer-price").text();
    var price = Number(pp.substring(1, pp.length));
    var familyPrice = "£" + price * 4;
    $(this).find(".latest-offer-price").text(familyPrice);
   })
 }
 
 $('#change').click(function(){
  $('.latest-offer-price').text("£" + 50);
  updateGrid();
 });

updateGrid();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grid_3 alpha omega selected">
  <div>
   <p class="latest-type">
     <span class="latest-offer-price">£100</span> 
     <span>pp</span> 
   </p>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="change">Fake ajax: Change to 50</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But unfortunately it's not quite what I need, If the original value of pp is 100 and I run the code once, it will correctly calculate 400. If the user clicks on a filter that will change the price to 50£ I see for a second 200£ and then it will automatically re-run the whole function and change the amount back to (400x4). That's because when the function runs again the 400 which is the new value of the span will be re-assigned to pp.